# is there a way to do one subscription but two callbacks (one debouced?)

Tags: rxjs

I have:

```
thingie.valueChanges.pipe(
  takeUntil(this.destroy$)
).subscribe(() => doSomething());

thingie.valueChanges.pipe(
  takeUntil(this.destroy$),
  debouce(250),
  mergeMap((x) => forMergeMap(x))
).subscribe((x) => doSomethingWithX(x));
```

Is there any way to combine that into one subscribe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `merge` function of `rxJs`.

For example:

```
const nonDebounced$ = thingie.valueChanges.pipe(
  map(() => ({ type: 'nonDebounced' }))
);

const debounced$ = thingie.valueChanges.pipe(
  debounceTime(250),
  mergeMap((x) => forMergeMap(x)),
  map((x) => ({ type: 'debounced', value: x }))
);

const combined$ = merge(nonDebounced$, debounced$).pipe(
  takeUntil(this.destroy$)
);
```

Then you can subscribe to it once and check the type value...

Comment: can I remove the individual `takeUntil`'s and do `merged(a,b).pipe(takeUntil(...))` ?

Comment: @patrick Yes, you can apply it in the merge. I will update my answer in a minute...

Answer (score 2):

You could simply do your callback logic  inside `tap`:

```js
thingie.valueChanges.pipe(
  tap(() => doSomething()),
  debouce(250),
  mergeMap(x => forMergeMap(x)),
  tap(x => doSomethingWithX(x)),
  takeUntil(this.destroy$)
).subscribe();
```

Comment: This is more ideal solution.